# Move Window by clicking on any part (as on Linux)?

Tags: keyboard, window-manager

On Linux (or X in general), it's possible to move a window while holding down a modifier key (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+*drag* or <kbd>Super</kbd>+*drag*) and clicking on ANY part of the window.

This makes moving windows super easy, as one doesn't have to aim so well ;)

On macOS (High Sierra), this doesn't seem to be enabled/possible by default.

How do I enable this or what add on do I need?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the free utility called "Easy Move+Resize", which allows you to use Cmd + Ctrl + Left click anywhere inside a window to move it. The modifier keys can be customized so that you can choose for example Alt + Left click instead.

You can download the utility from here:

https://github.com/dmarcotte/easy-move-resize

Read under the heading "Installation".

Comment: Excellent, this tool works fine for me :) Resizing sometimes doesn't seem to work so well, but that's not as important as dragging - which DOES work :)

Comment: You might also checkout HammerSpoon (http://www.hammerspoon.org/). If you are not afraid to edit an init file you customize it to your personal use. It does window re-sizing and placement with configurable keyboard commands no clicking required.

Answer (score 22):

For High Sierra (macOS 10.13) or later:

Shortcut: `Ctrl + Cmd + Click` to move windows.

Run below command in terminal to **enable** the shortcut. Restart after.

```
defaults write -g NSWindowShouldDragOnGesture -bool true
```

Run below command in terminal to **disable** the shortcut. Restart after.

```
defaults delete -g NSWindowShouldDragOnGesture
```

Reference: http://www.mackungfu.org/UsabilityhackClickdraganywhereinmacOSwindowstomovethem

Comment: This works great!

Comment: This is definitely the right answer

Comment: This is indeed the best and most acceptable answer. It simply works, without the need for any additional or 3rd party tool.

Comment: Awesome! Is there any way the shortcut keys can be changed?

Comment: It doesn't work on my macOS 13

Comment: Working here for me on macOS 13 (Ventura).  Don't forgot to reboot!

Comment: NOT working on Ventura 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a)

Comment: Working here on Ventura 13.4 on an M1.  Had to reboot.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS 13 but not so far on the macOS 14 beta 1

Answer (score 1):

BetterTouchTool has worked for me forever for this with no hiccups. Still ok on Mojave Beta 18E184e. It's got lots of other useful stuff, none of which I've used.

Comment: Can you describe or share the settings for enabling this feature in BTT?

Comment: @waldauf  My BTT version is 2.428. MacOS 10.14.6. Open BTT/Advanced/Window Moving & Resizing. I've chosen to be able to move the focused window, and I have chosen shift c/w ctrl for move, and shift c/w opt for resize, as these are easy to use with the left hand while my right hand is on the trackpad.

Answer (score 0):

The best application for this is Zooom2. Unfortunately in 2016 the author shut down the project [1] and the only place to download it is off of 3rd party mirror sites [2]. Luckily it's still working in OS X High Sierra as of this writing. It's a shame that the author did not open source his work.

[1] http://coderage-software.com/index.html

[2] https://download.cnet.com/Zooom/3000-18487_4-126030.html